# laravel custom request edit unique

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-request

i have custom request on laravel 5.5
this is the request

```
public function rules()
{
    if($this->method() == 'POST')
    {
        return [
            'user_name' => 'required|unique:users|max:40|min:1',
            'user_email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:40|min:3',
            'user_phone' => 'required|max:40|min:1',
            'password' => 'required|min:3',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|max:2048',
        ];          
    }
    elseif($this->method() == 'PATCH')
    {
        return [
            'user_name' => 'required|min:1|max:40|unique:users,user_name,'.$this->id,
            'user_email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:40|min:3',
            'user_phone' => 'required|max:40|min:1',
            'password' => 'required|min:3',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|max:2048',
        ];              
    }
```

now on method path 
i want to to ignore the current unique id 
and i wrote it like this

```
'user_name' => 'required|min:1|max:40|unique:users,user_name,'.$this->id,
```

but its always telling me thats the username you are trying to update is already in use 
i dont want to do that from the controller 
i want to do it in the request 
thanks

Comment: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `user_name` = pulldozer and `id` <>  this is the sql statment in last and id <> there is no value

Comment: Is it the authenticated user or other user update ?

Comment: other users update i cant use Auth::user->id

Comment: then you should add a hidden input with the name `id` that contain the updated user id !!

Comment: i add this to plade   <input type='hidden' name='id' value='{{$user->id}}' />  
 and still gat The user name has already been taken.

Comment: Replace `$this->id` with `$this->request->get('id')` !

Comment: i tried this $this->request->get('id') and this $this->get('id') and this $this->id still gat no value in the id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `$this->id`, here `$this` is not a User class but a Request instance, you may consider using `$this->user()->id` or `auth()->id()` or `Auth::id()` instead. if you have user id in route like `users/{userId}`, you can also use `$this->route('userId')`.